# Temporary user-profiles on Windows Server 2008 TS

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy, remote-desktop, windows-terminal-services

for a publicly accessible terminal server I have created a user profile which only allows running of a few programs (demonstration of applications).

This results in many people connecting to the same user name on the server, essentially sharing the same profile.

How can I copy the original, empty profile on every logon to a seperate directory and delete it afterwards, so everybody starts with a clean copy of the "Guest"-Account?

Answer (score 1):

Mandatory User Profiles may be what you need:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776895(VS.85).aspx

As Administrator, rename the guest NTuser.dat file (the registry hive) on the server to NTuser.man

Changes can be made to the profile whilst logged in, but these are lost when the user logs out.

Comment: Why didn't I find this? Thank you a lot! This still leaves the second part open: How do I do the same with the profile FILES and FOLDERS? They have to be reverted too. Do I just flat-out run a logoff script that deletes everything? People shouldn't share this profile folder... Because maybe some applications save profile data which shouldn't interfere with other users. (This is a big maybe though. We could manage it without)